# Django nonrel Models

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I have been looking at the documentation on django nonrel but think i have confused my self.

I have a project using the setup instructions found at http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation and continued to setup a django application. I am making a simple news feed.  Now it has come to create the models but there appears to be two ways of doing this, using models.Model or db.Model.

models.Model is the django way of doing it, and if I create a model using this it appears to use nosql, this also allows me use of the built in admin.

db.Models is the non-rel way of doing things. If I create the model using this is appears to use nosql again but this method does not let me make use of the django admin. I thought the point of django non-rel was to let me make use of the admin and a majority of the default functionality in django.

I would also like to ask what is the difference between django non-rel and pure django on app engine and how does this affect how the models are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

> db.Models is the non-rel way of doing things

Where did you get this idea? `db.Models` is the *AppEngine* way of doing things. django-nonrel allows you to use the Django way even though you're on AppEngine. As you say, the point of django-nonrel is to allow you to use the admin etc, for which you need to do things the Django way, ie `models.Model`.

Comment: So using django-non-rel I can do models.CharField(max_length=50), and queries this way : News.objects.get(title='first-news-article')

Comment: so what is the point of using djangoappengine with django nonrel if non-rel does everything djangoappengine does? 

Also does djangoappengine integrate with the built in django admin?

Comment: What? djangoappengine is the plugin for django-nonrel that applies it to AppEngine. You can't use either on its own.

Comment: Man I cam so confused by all this, I have obviously missed something major along the way. I think the thing that has confused me is seeing tutorials using models which contain StringProperty, but people saying you cannot then use the admin.

Is it the case that StringProperty() actually maps to CharField()?

Comment: I don't know what's confusing you. db.StringProperty, like db.Model, is from the standard AppEngine db library. These are incompatible with the admin. django-nonrel + djangoappengine replaces these with the Django versions: models.CharField and models.Model. These can be used with the admin.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of knowledge but in some examples why do people use the db.StringProperty() instead of CharField() when using django nonrel on appengine. Surely this is massively counter productive?

Comment: "some examples" - for instance?